file-expand-wildcards for find-sibling-rules appears broken on Windows
I can't seem to create a find-sibling-rules that works properly in Windows, and I don't believe the documentation example will work on Windows either.
The issue is that file-expand-wildcards apparently can't handle all regular expression constructs, as attempting to use grouping or alternation in the pattern causes nothing to match.
Also, \. doesn't seem to work to force a file extension match. [.] does work.
Does anyone have a successful example of rules that work on Windows?

What do file-expand-wildcards and find-sibling-rules have in common? AFAICT, they are completely different things used for different purposes. Can you please provide a description of what you are trying to do? Adding an example might help.

Please don't use the elisp tag here - see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info for a description of where it should be used. It is rather specialized and should be used very rarely.

find-sibling-rules is a variable that is only used by two functions: find-sibling-file and find-sibling-file-search. Please read their docstrings (e.g. C-h f find-sibling-file) to find out what they do.

@NickD I know what they do. If you look at the code for find-sibling-file you will see that it calls file-expand-wildcards when rules are matched from find-sibling-rules. Did you try the documentation examples?

@NickD Thank you for cleaning up tags. This Stack seems to be lacking in tags - file-expand-wildcards is a library function included with emacs but there seems to be no tag for questions involving those.

files seemed appropriate: what would you suggest? As for your previous comment, yes, I did and they work as expected (but I'm on Linux - OTOH, all this stuff is just Lisp, so it's unlikely that Windows would break them, but who knows?) Now, could you provide an example of what does not work so we can make some progress? Your setting of find-sibling-rules, an example directory hierarchy and your invocation of find-sibling-file would suffice.

The values here are strings representing regular expressions. This means that you need to duplicate any "" characters. In your example, "\." would be the equivalent to "[.]" and not "." which is equivalent to "."

@NickD The documentation example is a rule that doesn't work as I mentioned in my question?

And as I mentioned, in reply to your "Did you try the documentation examples?", yes, I did and they work as expected (but I'm on Linux - OTOH, all this stuff is just Lisp, so it's unlikely that Windows would break them, but who knows?)
